# Not able to make te build on Server

Tags: node.js, module, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, font-awesome

I hope you are doing well. I have a project in NodeJs, NuxtJs(frontend) with Tailwind css but when I am trying to make the build on live server then I am facing the error but at the same its working fine on localhost, here is steps that I have tried

**=> All the modules are reinstalled**

**=> Cleared the cache by using command npm run clear-cache**

Mainly I am facing the error with Tailwind CSS so for this I have reinstalled/updated the module on server but still facing same issue.

Here is error that I am facing

```
/home/martel10/nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/.cache/nuxt/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' in '/home/martel10/nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/.cache/nuxt'
@ /home/martel10/nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/.cache/nuxt/App.js 24:0-120
@ /home/martel10/nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
@ /home/martel10/nodevenv/public_html/smartcardtwo/14/lib/node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
@ multi ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
```

Its saying that module not found but I have cross checked and modules are already there in same directory.

Here is screenshot URL - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIYf.png

Can I anyone help me to sort this issue, I'll really appreciate for your help.

Thanks

=> All the modules are reinstalled
=> Cleared the cache by using command npm run clear-cache